# Wrapped error with setup_databases for pytest-django

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

After I added a new class to my models, I am unable to run my tests in my server. The problem is the error message seems to be wrapped and doesn't provide further information about the error. As you can see, the table doesn't exist in the database, as expected, but why can't I retrieve more information why it fails to "setup_databases"?

I am using SQLITE to perform these tests. A file should be created and the migrations applied. I can run it with no problem on my computer, but in the server I can't. It simply fails with the stack bellow.

My struggle lasts almost 3 days now, and I have no idea what I can do to fix this thing.

**Things to notice:** I use `factory boy`, `GitLab` and as you can see, `pytest-django`.

#### coverage_report.sh

```
/bin/py.test --cov=. --cov-report=term-missing --no-cov-on-fail --cov-fail-under=90 v3 api web
```

#### settings for test

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}
```

#### pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=v3.settings_testing
markers =
    integration
    unittest
    selenium
```

#### test_classes.py

```
class CustomerReputationFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomerReputation

    customer = factory.SubFactory(CustomerFactory)
    reputation = factory.SubFactory(ReputationFactory)
    assignment_reason = "Reason for tag assignment"

class ReputationFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Reputation

    tag_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "reputation-tag-%d" % n)
    description = "I am a reputation tag"
    warning_level = 'CW'
    disabled = False

class TestAddCustomerReputation:
    @pytest.fixture
    def prerequisites(self, db):
        customer = factories.CustomerFactory()
        customer_reputation = factories.CustomerReputationFactory.create_batch(3)
        reputations = factories.ReputationFactory.create_batch(3)
        return {
            'customer': customer,
            'reputations': reputations,
            'customer_reputation': customer_reputation
        }

    @pytest.mark.integration
    def test_can_add_reputation(self, prerequisites, db):
        customer_reputation = prerequisites['customer_reputation']
        customer = prerequisites['customer']
        reputations = prerequisites['reputations']

        customer_reputation[0].customer = customer
        customer_reputation[0].reputation = reputations[0]
        customer_reputation[0].assignment_description = "Bad customer"
        customer_reputation[0].save()

        assert reputations[0] in customer.reputation.all()
        assert reputations[1] not in customer.reputation.all()
```

#### part of the stack

Just part, since it is a bit big. All tests that require database access fail.

```
$ ./coverage_report.sh ./env
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.3, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
django settings: v3.settings_testing (from ini file)
rootdir: /home/gitlab_ci_multi_runner/builds/3e679c18/0/company-staff/project, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-2.9.1, cov-2.3.0, mock-1.1, xdist-1.14
collected 565 items

v3/tests/test_flattened_proxy_models.py EEEEEEEEE
v3/tests/test_managers.py EEEEEEEE
v3/tests/test_services.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEE
v3/tests/test_zendesk.py ................
api/tests/test_api.py EEE
api/tests/test_filters.py ..EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
api/tests/test_viewsets.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_accounts.py EEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_addresses.py EEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_agreements.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_calc_vat.py EEEE
web/tests/test_check_vat.py ......
web/tests/test_collection_utils.py ...
web/tests/test_config.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_contacts.py EEEEEEE
web/tests/test_custom_invoice_lines.py EEEE
web/tests/test_customers.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_files.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_forms.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_initial_data.py EE
web/tests/test_invoices.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_license_import.py EEEEE
web/tests/test_login.py .EEEE
web/tests/test_markdown_template.py .E
web/tests/test_models.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_payments.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_product.py EEEEEE
web/tests/test_profile.py EEE
web/tests/test_querysets.py EEEE
web/tests/test_report.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_shipping.py EEE
web/tests/test_tasks.py EEEEEEEEE
web/tests/test_todo.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
___ ERROR at setup of TestFlattenedProxyModel.test_original_must_be_provided ___

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_setup' for <Function 'test_original_must_be_provided'>>
_django_test_environment = None
_django_cursor_wrapper = <pytest_django.plugin.CursorManager object at 0x7f670846bcf8>

    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def _django_db_setup(request,
                         _django_test_environment,
                         _django_cursor_wrapper):
        """Session-wide database setup, internal to pytest-django"""
        skip_if_no_django()

        from .compat import setup_databases, teardown_databases

        # xdist
        if hasattr(request.config, 'slaveinput'):
            db_suffix = request.config.slaveinput['slaveid']
        else:
            db_suffix = None

        monkey_patch_creation_for_db_suffix(db_suffix)

        _handle_south()

        if request.config.getvalue('nomigrations'):
            _disable_native_migrations()

        with _django_cursor_wrapper:
            # Monkey patch Django's setup code to support database re-use
            if request.config.getvalue('reuse_db'):
                if not request.config.getvalue('create_db'):
                    monkey_patch_creation_for_db_reuse()

            # Create the database
            db_cfg = setup_databases(verbosity=pytest.config.option.verbose,
>                                    interactive=False)

env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:54: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py:370: in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:376: in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:413: in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py:129: in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py:52: in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:409: in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:238: in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:840: in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:97: in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py:658: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x7f67068f8af8>
query = 'SELECT "v3_customerreputation"."id", "v3_customerreputation"."created_at", "v3_customerreputation"."updated_at", "v3_...d", "v3_customerreputation"."assignment_reason" FROM "v3_customerreputation" ORDER BY "v3_customerreputation"."id" ASC'
params = ()

    def execute(self, query, params=None):
        if params is None:
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
        query = self.convert_query(query)
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
E       django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: v3_customerreputation

env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:318: OperationalError
_ ERROR at setup of TestFlattenedProxyModel.test_fields_match_original_fields __

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_setup' for <Function 'test_original_must_be_provided'>>
_django_test_environment = None
_django_cursor_wrapper = <pytest_django.plugin.CursorManager object at 0x7f670846bcf8>

    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def _django_db_setup(request,
                         _django_test_environment,
                         _django_cursor_wrapper):
        """Session-wide database setup, internal to pytest-django"""
        skip_if_no_django()

        from .compat import setup_databases, teardown_databases

        # xdist
        if hasattr(request.config, 'slaveinput'):
            db_suffix = request.config.slaveinput['slaveid']
        else:
            db_suffix = None

        monkey_patch_creation_for_db_suffix(db_suffix)

        _handle_south()

        if request.config.getvalue('nomigrations'):
            _disable_native_migrations()

        with _django_cursor_wrapper:
            # Monkey patch Django's setup code to support database re-use
            if request.config.getvalue('reuse_db'):
                if not request.config.getvalue('create_db'):
                    monkey_patch_creation_for_db_reuse()

            # Create the database
            db_cfg = setup_databases(verbosity=pytest.config.option.verbose,
>                                    interactive=False)

env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:54: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py:370: in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:376: in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:413: in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py:129: in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py:52: in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:409: in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:238: in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:840: in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:97: in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py:658: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x7f67068f8af8>
query = 'SELECT "v3_customerreputation"."id", "v3_customerreputation"."created_at", "v3_customerreputation"."updated_at", "v3_...d", "v3_customerreputation"."assignment_reason" FROM "v3_customerreputation" ORDER BY "v3_customerreputation"."id" ASC'
params = ()

    def execute(self, query, params=None):
        if params is None:
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
        query = self.convert_query(query)
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
E       django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: v3_customerreputation

env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:318: OperationalError
_ ERROR at setup of TestSellerInformationProxy.test_all_fields_properly_copied _

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_setup' for <Function 'test_original_must_be_provided'>>
_django_test_environment = None
_django_cursor_wrapper = <pytest_django.plugin.CursorManager object at 0x7f670846bcf8>

    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def _django_db_setup(request,
                         _django_test_environment,
                         _django_cursor_wrapper):
        """Session-wide database setup, internal to pytest-django"""
        skip_if_no_django()

        from .compat import setup_databases, teardown_databases

        # xdist
        if hasattr(request.config, 'slaveinput'):
            db_suffix = request.config.slaveinput['slaveid']
        else:
            db_suffix = None

        monkey_patch_creation_for_db_suffix(db_suffix)

        _handle_south()

        if request.config.getvalue('nomigrations'):
            _disable_native_migrations()

        with _django_cursor_wrapper:
            # Monkey patch Django's setup code to support database re-use
            if request.config.getvalue('reuse_db'):
                if not request.config.getvalue('create_db'):
                    monkey_patch_creation_for_db_reuse()

            # Create the database
            db_cfg = setup_databases(verbosity=pytest.config.option.verbose,
>                                    interactive=False)

env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:54: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py:370: in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:376: in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:413: in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py:129: in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py:52: in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:409: in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:238: in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:840: in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:97: in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py:658: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x7f67068f8af8>
query = 'SELECT "v3_customerreputation"."id", "v3_customerreputation"."created_at", "v3_customerreputation"."updated_at", "v3_...d", "v3_customerreputation"."assignment_reason" FROM "v3_customerreputation" ORDER BY "v3_customerreputation"."id" ASC'
params = ()

    def execute(self, query, params=None):
        if params is None:
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
        query = self.convert_query(query)
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
E       django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: v3_customerreputation

env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:318: OperationalError
______ ERROR at setup of TestAddressProxy.test_all_fields_properly_copied ______

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_setup' for <Function 'test_original_must_be_provided'>>
_django_test_environment = None
_django_cursor_wrapper = <pytest_django.plugin.CursorManager object at 0x7f670846bcf8>

    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def _django_db_setup(request,
                         _django_test_environment,
                         _django_cursor_wrapper):
        """Session-wide database setup, internal to pytest-django"""
        skip_if_no_django()

        from .compat import setup_databases, teardown_databases

        # xdist
        if hasattr(request.config, 'slaveinput'):
            db_suffix = request.config.slaveinput['slaveid']
        else:
            db_suffix = None

        monkey_patch_creation_for_db_suffix(db_suffix)

        _handle_south()

        if request.config.getvalue('nomigrations'):
            _disable_native_migrations()

        with _django_cursor_wrapper:
            # Monkey patch Django's setup code to support database re-use
            if request.config.getvalue('reuse_db'):
                if not request.config.getvalue('create_db'):
                    monkey_patch_creation_for_db_reuse()

            # Create the database
            db_cfg = setup_databases(verbosity=pytest.config.option.verbose,
>                                    interactive=False)

env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:54: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py:370: in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:376: in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:413: in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py:129: in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py:52: in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:409: in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:238: in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:840: in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:97: in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py:658: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x7f67068f8af8>
query = 'SELECT "v3_customerreputation"."id", "v3_customerreputation"."created_at", "v3_customerreputation"."updated_at", "v3_...d", "v3_customerreputation"."assignment_reason" FROM "v3_customerreputation" ORDER BY "v3_customerreputation"."id" ASC'
params = ()

    def execute(self, query, params=None):
        if params is None:
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
        query = self.convert_query(query)
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
E       django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: v3_customerreputation

env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:318: OperationalError
______ ERROR at setup of TestContactProxy.test_all_fields_properly_copied ______

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_setup' for <Function 'test_original_must_be_provided'>>
_django_test_environment = None
_django_cursor_wrapper = <pytest_django.plugin.CursorManager object at 0x7f670846bcf8>

    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def _django_db_setup(request,
                         _django_test_environment,
                         _django_cursor_wrapper):
        """Session-wide database setup, internal to pytest-django"""
        skip_if_no_django()

        from .compat import setup_databases, teardown_databases

        # xdist
        if hasattr(request.config, 'slaveinput'):
            db_suffix = request.config.slaveinput['slaveid']
        else:
            db_suffix = None

        monkey_patch_creation_for_db_suffix(db_suffix)

        _handle_south()

        if request.config.getvalue('nomigrations'):
            _disable_native_migrations()

        with _django_cursor_wrapper:
            # Monkey patch Django's setup code to support database re-use
            if request.config.getvalue('reuse_db'):
                if not request.config.getvalue('create_db'):
                    monkey_patch_creation_for_db_reuse()

            # Create the database
            db_cfg = setup_databases(verbosity=pytest.config.option.verbose,
>                                    interactive=False)
```

Comment: @eldamir remember seeing anything like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after hours I found out I was forgetting to commit my migrations to GitLab. `pytest-django` didn't know what to migrate, therefore the problem.